# OpenCV copyTo assert error

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

While copying one Mat into the region of interest of another I came accross an error I've never seen before. Googling it didn't turn up many results and none of them seems to be relevant.

I have included a screenshot of the error as well as some properties of the Mat's.

[image]

This is the code:

```
    std::cout << "size height,width: " << size.height << ", " << size.width << std::endl;
    cv::Mat tempResult(size.width, size.height, result.type());

    std::cout << "tempResult cols,rows: " << tempResult.cols << ", " << tempResult.rows << std::endl;
    std::cout << "tempResult type: " << tempResult.type() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "tempResult channels: " << tempResult.channels() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "result cols,rows: " << result.cols << ", " << result.rows << std::endl;
    std::cout << "result type: " << result.type() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "result channels: " << result.channels() << std::endl;

    cv::Rect rect(0, 0, result.cols-1, result.rows-1);

    std::cout << "rect size: " << rect.size() << std::endl;
    result.copyTo(tempResult(rect));
```

Comment: try  result(rect).copyTo(tempResult(rect));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cv::Mat::operator(cv::Rect roi)` method extract a submatrix with the same size of the cv::Rect roi.
But you defined a cv::Rect object with 1 row and 1 col missing, so the output matrix returned by `tempResult(rect)` is smaller the the matrix `result`. `cv::Mat::CopyTo` launch an exception because the input to copy is smaller than the output argument.

To fix this :

```
cv::Rect rect(0, 0, result.cols, result.rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

For [**`cv::Rect`**](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#rect), its format is `(x, y, width, height)`, not `(x1, y1, x2, y2)`. That's why, in my opinion, you get the error.

If yes, you will need to change `rect` to:

```
cv::Rect rect(0, 0, result.cols, result.rows);
```

If not (i.e. you really means `rect(x, y, width-1, height-1)`), you can do like this:

```
result(rect).copyTo(tempResult(rect));
```