# Copying bottom portion of cv::Mat to another cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I am only interested in performing HoughLinesP on the bottom half of an image, for performance reasons, so I would like to copy the bottom portion of one image to another image of the same size.  It is important to maintain image size because I need to keep the lines detected relative to the original image.

I have tried to adapt [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137766/copying-region-of-an-image-to-another-region-in-another-image) solution with the following code:

```
int startpoint{ 240 };
cv::Mat houghlinesmat{ image.size(), image.type(), cv::Scalar(0) };
houghlinesmat.setTo(0);
image.copyTo( houghlinesmat(cv::Rect(0,
                                     startpoint,
                                     image.cols,
                                     image.rows - startpoint)) );
```

However, I always receive a copyTo assert error similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217722/opencv-copyto-assert-error) example.  However, it does not appear to me to be an issue of being 1 row or column off.  It seems more that I cannot copy a cv:rect smaller than the output without error.  Any idea what's missing?

Comment: Have you checked the sizes of both cv::Mats?

Comment: When I initialize houghlinesmat, I do it with image.size(), so they should be  the same size.  But it is an easy check, I'll go ahead and do that in a few minutes.

Comment: I checked, images are the same size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found some direction to the final solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481411/copy-an-cvmat-inside-a-roi-of-another-one), see last comment.

Adapted:

```
image( cv::Rect(0,
                startpoint,
                image.cols,
                image.rows -
                startpoint)).copyTo(houghlinesmat(cv::Rect(0,
                startpoint,
                image.cols,
                image.rows -
                startpoint)));
```

A bit messy looking in the end but exactly what I wanted.  Essentially I wasn't specifying both the source and destination regions, so the size didn't match.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
image.copyTo( houghlinesmat, cv::Rect(0,
                                     startpoint,
                                     image.cols,
                                     image.rows - startpoint));
```

Be careful with the size of the mask.

Comment: No luck, compile error: "error: no matching function for call to 'cv::Mat::copyTo(cv::Mat&, cv::Rect)'".